# How to read content of a blob and write to GAE datastore (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore, datastore

How to read content of a blob and write to GAE datastore in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`FileService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService) API to create/write/read files in Blobstore. When you read byte array from file, then you can easily add as a property to Datastore entity and save it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the [BlobKey](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobKey) for the blob you want to read, you can construct a [BlobstoreInputStream](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream):

```
BlobKey blobKey = ...;
InputStream is = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey)
```

You can then read the blob contents using any of the InputStream read methods.